# How do I replace all the blanks within specific columns to a specified string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with the following VBA code, with summarizes some survey results :

```
Sub Main()


   ReplaceBlanks
   Multi_FindReplace

End Sub


Sub ReplaceBlanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Refined")
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
     If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 17), ws.Cells(i, 21))) = 0 Then
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
              Set rng = Union(ws.Cells(i, 1), rng)
        Else
              Set rng = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
     End If
Next i

rng.EntireRow.Delete


End Sub


Sub Multi_FindReplace()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Mostly satisfied", "Completely satisfied", "N/A", "Not at all satisfied")
rplcList = Array("Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Not satisfied")



Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Refined")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook

        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


  Next x

End Sub
```

This code produces output that shows only the phrases "Satisfied" or "Not Satisfied."  The picture below shows how it look :

[image]

However, when it's finished it also shows some blank cells, which I would like to also say "Satisfied " ( but we only want to do this after removing the empty lines where survey respondents didn't answer any question at all (this is accomplished already by the "ReplaceBlanks" sub-function ) .

The blank cells I want to focus on are only those that are in columns Q3 to U3 ,  then W3 to Z3  , and finally  AB3 to AC3 downward ( i.e I don't know how many rows there will be in those columns, but at least one  and starting at row 3. )

I am not sure about how to focus only on those 3 groups of columns, but I tried the following code on the first group :

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each r In Range("Q3:U19" & LastRow)
        If r.Text = "" Then r.Value = "Satisfied"
    Next r
End Sub
```

but this one put "Satisfied" in an extra thousand rows below the group which I needed !!

Any tips appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub dural()    
    With Sheets("Refined")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("Q:U, W:Z, AB:AC")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "Satisfied"
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW: `"Q3:U19" & LastRow` is bound to return some "Q3:Q19xxx" address, with xxx being equal to LastRow...

Comment: Thanks very much  - so I take it there is no way to stop at the last row of data when replacing the empty-cells with "Satisfy"  ,

Comment: This is brilliant way to do it though ,  & But it's easy to delete the excess data  -

Comment: all's well now Thanks